# How to remove column with number as index name?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

I tried to drop the data of `-1` column by using

```
df = df.drop(columns=['-1'])
```

However, it is giving me the following error:

[image]

I was able to drop the column if the column name is some language character using this similar coding script, but not a number. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test real columns names by converting them to list:

```
print (df.columns.tolist())
```

---

I think you need droping number `-1` instead string `'-1'`:

```
df = df.drop(columns=[-1])
```

Or another solution with same ouput:

```
df = df.drop(-1, axis=1)
```

EDIT:

If need select all columns without first use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select by position, first `:` means select all rows and second `1:` all columns with omit first:

```
df = df.iloc[:, 1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to remove the first column, another approach that would be independent of the column name is this:

```
df = df[df.columns[1:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it simply by using the following code:

first check the name of the column by using following:

```
df.columns
```

then if the output is like:

```
Index(['-1', '0'], dtype='object')
```

use drop command to delete the column

```
df.drop(['-1'], axis =1, inplace = True)
```

guess this should help for future as well